# Counting every 5th for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I'm having a hard time with this problem here:

> Write a function named sumEvery5th that accepts a non-negative integer `n` and returns the sum of the integers divisible by 5 from 1 to `n`, including `n` itself. Use a `for` loop.

This is what I have so far:

```
var sumEvery5th = function(n){

    let sum = 0;
    for(let i = 1; n % 5 == 0; i++){
        sum+ i
    };
    return sum;
}
```

I feel like I'm really close. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: `n %5 == 0` if that is false, the for loop stops ... you need an `if` condition inside the for loop (or the shortcut as shown in the answer below)

Answer (score 3):

You can start your loop at `5`, since 1, 2... are not divisible by 5. And instead of `i++`, you can directly go 5 by 5, until `i` is greater than `n`:

```js
var sumEvery5th = function(n) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 5; i <= n; i += 5) {
    sum += i;
  };
  return sum;
}

console.log(sumEvery5th(10)); // 5 + 10 = 15
console.log(sumEvery5th(18)); // 5 + 10 + 15 = 30
```

Answer (score 2):

First I think you should understand how a `for` loop works.

```
var sumEvery5th = function(n){
    let sum = 0;
    for(let i = 1; n % 5 == 0; i++){
        sum+ i
    };
    return sum;
}
```

What you are doing, step by step, is:

1. Declaring a variable `i` with value 1.
2. Dividing `n` by 5 and taking the remainder value and comparing it with 0. In case it's true, you are skipping the code block inside the for and moving towards the `return sum;` line.
3. (In case you haven't skipped the code block in step 2) Run the code block with the new `i` value.
4. (In case you haven't skipped the code block in step 2) Incrementing the i value.
5. Go back to step 2.

**Usually** your `for` condition will depend in the variable declared in step 1. What you want to do is run the `for` code block `n` times.
For that, you need to change your condition from `n % 5 == 0` to `i <= n`. This will make sure to run the code block while your `i` is less or equal than `n`, starting with a value of 1.

Now, inside your code block you add your `divisible by 5` logic, checking against `i` value.

```
for(let i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    if (i%5 == 0) sum += i;
};
```

Now let's say I called sumEvery5th(5).

1. Declare a variable i with value 1.
2. Check if `i` (1) is less than or equal `n` (5).
3. Go inside the code block.
4. Check if i%5 is 0.
5. It's not.
6. Increment i, now i = 2.
7. Check if `i` (2) is less than or equal `n` (5).
   ...And so on, until i = 6, and in that case the code block is skipped and the program will continue its course.

Ps.: There are ways to improve the performance of this algorithm, but now that you understand your `for` loop a bit better I'll leave it to you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var sumEvery5th = function(n){

    let sum = 0;
    for(let i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        if (i % 5 === 0) {
            sum += i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.